# How to count how many words are in line?Smarter way?

Tags: c++

How to find out how many words are in line? I now that method where you count how many there are spaces. But what if someone hit 2 spaces or start line with space.

Is there any other or smarter way to solve this?

And is there any remark on my way of solving it or my code?

I solved it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main( )
{
    char str[80];

    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    cin.getline(str,80);

    int len;

    len=strlen(str);

    int words = 0;

    for(int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) //is space after character
    {
        if (isalpha(str[i])) 
        {
            if(isspace(str[i+1]))
            words++;
        }       
    }

    if(isalpha(str[len]))
    {
        words++;
    }

    cout << "The number of words = " << words+1 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes there is a very "smart" and simple way, using a single call to [`std::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) together with [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator). That will make your `main` function only a couple of lines long. But perhaps that's not the purpose of the exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

streams by default skip spaces (multiple also).

So if you do something like:

```
string word;
int numWords = 0;
while (cin >> word) ++numWords;
```

That should count the number of words for simple cases (not considering what the format of a word is, skipping spaces).

If you want per line, you could read first the line, create a stream from a string, and do a similar thing like this:

```
string line, word;
int wordCount = 0;
getline(cin, line);
stringstream lineStream(line);
while (lineStream >> word) ++wordCount;
```

You should not use `cin.getline` and should prefer the free function `std::getline`, which takes a string that can be grown up and prevents stack overflows (lol). Stick to the free function for better safety.

Comment: Can you give me a link to good explanation of `<sstream>`, i assume you are using that library ?

Comment: sstream is standard. It is a stream like cin but uses the given string as the source of data.

Answer (score 3):

The std one-liner is:

```
words= distance(istream_iterator<string>(istringstream(str)), istream_iterator<string>());
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a very specific definition of "word."  Most of the answers will give slightly different counts than your attempt because you're using different definitions of what constitutes a word.  Your example specifically requires alpha characters in certain positions.  The answers based on streams will allow any non-space character to be part of a word.

The general solution is to come up with a precise definition of a word, transform this into a regular  expression or finite state machine, and then count each instance of a match.

Here's a sample state machine solution:

```
std::size_t CountWords(const std::string &line) {
    std::size_t count = 0;
    enum { between_words, in_word } state = between_words;
    for (const auto c : line) {
        switch (state) {
            case between_words:
                if (std::isalpha(c)) {
                    state = in_word;
                    ++count;
                }
                break;
            case in_word:
                if (std::isspace(c)) state = between_words;
                break;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Some test cases to consider (and that highlight the differences among the definitions of a word):

- `""` empty string
- `"   "`  just spaces
- `"a"`
- `"   one   "`
- `"count two"`
- `"hyphenated-word"`
- `"\"That's Crazy!\" she said."`  punctuation between alpha characters and adjacent spaces
- `"the answer is 42"`  should the number count as a word?